# How to bind ion-button in ionic 4?

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am making an app like Instagram, were the user can follow, unfollow, get a list of user following and followers. In the following, I am displaying the following user list and here I want to bind to follow/unfollow button.

page.html

```
 <ion-item lines="none" *ngFor="let u of user" (click)="openuserProfile(u.UserId)">
  <ion-avatar slot="start">
    <img [src]="profileImgDomain + u?.ProfileImage">
  </ion-avatar>
  <ion-label>
    <h2>{{u?.Name}}</h2>
    <p>{{u?.UserName}}</p>
    <p>{{u?.Bio}}</p>
  </ion-label>
  <ion-button slot="end" (click)="toggleFollow(u.UserId);$event.stopPropagation();" fill="outline"
    size="small" shape="round" *ngIf="u?.IsFollow == 0">
    <span>Follow</span>
  </ion-button>
  <ion-button slot="end" (click)="toggleFollow(u.UserId);$event.stopPropagation();" fill="solid"
    size="small" shape="round" *ngIf="u?.IsFollow == 1">
    <span>Following</span>
  </ion-button>
</ion-item>
```

page.ts

```
getuserlist() {
 const value: {
   UserFollowId: string,
 } = {
   UserFollowId: this.useruid,
 };
 this.apiService.getFollowingUsers(value).then((data) => {
   this.user = data;
   console.log(data);
   console.log("IsFollow", this.user.IsFollow);
   if (!this.user.IsFollow) {
     this.IsFollow = false;
     this.btnfilltype = 'outline';
   } else if (this.user.IsFollow) {
     this.IsFollow = true;
     this.btnfilltype = 'solid';
   } else {
     alert("User not valid");
   }
 });
}

toggleFollow(UserId: string) {
const value: {
  logedUserId: any,
  userFollowId: string,
} = {
  logedUserId: this.currentUserId.__zone_symbol__value,
  userFollowId: UserId,
};
this.apiService.follow(value).then(async (success) => {
  console.log("succ", success);
  if (success = 0) {
    console.log(success, "Update success.");
    this.IsFollow = !this.IsFollow;
    this.btnfill = !this.btnfill;
    this.btnfilltype = 'outline';
  } else {
    this.IsFollow = !this.IsFollow;
    this.btnfill = !this.btnfill;
    this.btnfilltype = 'solid';
  }
}, error => {
  console.log("Error", error);
});
```

}

I try this but the toggle button is not working.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Do you get any error or does it just not toggle? Is your promised getting resolved?. Also `if (success = 0)` should probably be  `if (success === 0)`

Comment: This code is working when I bind single button but I don't know how to bind when data in the array list

Comment: can you share full ts file and full template file? also can you share what is typical "data" that you assign to this.user. I see also that in one place you use ngFor with "user" (hinting that "user" is an array) and then in another method you call "this.user.isFollow" (hinting that user is an object). Very confusing.